# Mongodb 3.2 and 3.0 $unwind aggregation

Tags: mongodb

I have created a query and check it in robomongo and it's working fine for me in mongodb 3.2

```
db.post.aggregate([
   {$unwind: {path: "$page_groups", preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true}},
   {$group: {_id: "$page_groups",
   page_names: {$addToSet: "$page_name"}}},
])
```

But unfortunantly I need to get same data in mongodb 3.0 
Can anyone tell me how to get data with empty array in mongo 3.0 and get results by array key?

Without $unwind I get objects where  pages have two or more groups and I don't need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To mimick the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` **[`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/)** option in 3.2 for 3.0 aggregation pipeline operations, generate an initial **[`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/#pipe._S_project)** pipeline stage that creates the array field if it's null or empty (using the **[`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/#exp._S_ifNull)** operator):

```
var pipeline = [
    {
        "$project": {
            "pg": {
                "$ifNull": [
                    "$page_groups",
                    ["Unspecified"]
                ]
            },
            "page_name": 1
        }
    },
    { "$unwind": "$page_groups" },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": "$page_groups",
            "page_names": { "$addToSet": "$page_name" }
        }
    }
];

db.collection.aggregate(pipeline);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for answere, I wanted to use $project at first, but I think I have found easier way using $match and array $size to ignore results where array gets more than one element:

```
db.post_summary.aggregate([
    {$match: {$or: 
        [{page_groups: {$size: 1}}, {page_groups: {$size: 0}}]}},
   {$group: {       
       _id: "$page_groups",
       page_names: { "$addToSet": "$page_name" }
   }},
])
```

In my case "page_groups" have this structure:

```
page_groups:[
    0 =>[_id, group_name] 
    1 =>[_id, group_name] 
]
```

Comment: Sorry, didn't  notice that my solution don't add data with several groups in the results, still finding solution.